# React Audio Player not playing recieved data from axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, get, buffer

I have a React Audio Player that and set it's src to an Axios "get" method response:

```
const [songName, setSongName] = useState("");
    const [response, setResponse] = useState("");
    //this function is linked to the GET request,
    const handleRetrieve = async (event) =>{
        //prevent the page from reloading
        event.preventDefault();
        //set the formData
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("songName", songName);
        console.log("formdata appended");
        console.log(formData);
        try{
            const res = await axios({
                method: "get",
                url: `http://localhost:8080/Uploadedfiles/${songName}`,
                data: formData
            });
            console.log("RESPONSE");
            console.log(res.data)
            setResponse(res.data);
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    };
    //response[data][1].data
    const handleNameSelect = (event) =>{
        setSongName(event.target.files[0].name);
    };
```

React-Audio-player:

```
<ReactAudioPlayer
        controls
        autoPlay
        src={response}/>
```

Input form:

```
<form onSubmit={handleRetrieve} encType="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Choose a song to play</label>
            <input type="file"  onChange={handleNameSelect}/>
            <input type="submit"/>
          </form>
```

The Back End:

```
app.get("/Uploadedfiles/:name", (req, res) => {
  console.log("For Audio Player");
  console.log("searching");
  const params = req.params.name;
  console.log(params);
  let red = read(params);
  console.log(red)
  //make an object that stores the name and the stored data
  let dataset = [params, red]
  //send this to the front end with res.send
  console.log(dataset);
  console.log("hi");
  //create a buffer from the data
  const buf = Buffer.from(red)
  //convert the buffer to a string
  let buffed = buf.toString("utf-8");
  //send the stringed buffer as the response
  res.send(buffed);
});
```

When I mouse over the player, it recieved the buffed data string, but for some reason it doesn't know to play the song once the data is inserted. Help pls

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if you're supposed to use Post or Get method, From your axios code that should be a Post request. Write a get request and make sure to include a responseType: 'blob'. Your query isn't clear though share more on your problem